# Formulario para celulares

Tags: javascript

gostaria de saber como faço uma validação de formulário para que não deixe os campos em branco nos celular, já fiz varios modos, no pc funciona mas no celular não funcionou de nenhum modo, como eu faria isso?

```
<script language="JavaScript">
    function ValidaSemPreenchimento(form) {
        for (i = 0; i < form.length; i++) {
            var obg = form[i].obrigatorio;
            if (obg == 1) {
                if (form[i].value == "") {
                    var nome = form[i].name
                    alert("Os campos chave é obrigatório.")
                    form[i].focus();
                    return false
                }
            }
        }
        return true
    }

</script>

<form name="form" id="form" action="send.php" method="post" onSubmit="return ValidaSemPreenchimento(this)">
```

Comment: Podes mostrar o código que estás a usar? Coloca tb o padrão de numeros que queres validar.

Comment: esta ai, editei o post !

Comment: O que é essa propriedade `.obrigatorio`? É um `id` ou `name`? onde está o HTML da(s) form(s)?

Comment: o form está em baixo amigo, a questão é que eu não quero que deixem em branco, que não envie o email ou passe de pagina se tiver algum input em branco daquela pagina!

Comment: Não use stacksnippets sem necessidade, eles não são pra formatar e sim pra executar códigos js+css+html que façam alguma coisa, se não for pra fazer nada use a marcação normal. Leia o HELP (http://pt.stackoverflow.com/help/formatting) e aprenda a siga o que é dito nele, não saia chutando as coisas sem ter certeza de como funcionam. Entendam como uma critica construtiva.

Comment: @LeonardoRibeiro junta mais informações à pergunta, assim como está ainda tenho dúvidas sobre o que queres.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Por que você não usa jQuery ? Será mais simples para não deixar que o input fique em branco caso o usuário tente enviar o formulário com campos brancos.

Você pode usar [este simples plugin](https://jqueryvalidation.org/) de jQuery.

**jQuery :**

```
$(document).ready(function () {

    $('#myform').validate({ // initialize the plugin
        rules: {
            field1: {
                required: true,
                email: true
            },
            field2: {
                required: true,
                minlength: 5
            }
        }
    });

});
```

**HTML :**

```
<form id="myform">
    <input type="text" name="field1" />
    <input type="text" name="field2" />
    <input type="submit" />
</form>
```

**Exemplo funcionando com este código :**   http://jsfiddle.net/xs5vrrso/

**Outras opções :** https://jqueryvalidation.org/validate

**Plugins :** https://jqueryvalidation.org/category/plugin/

Comment: Usar jQuery só para "não deixar que o input fique em branco " é como matar uma mosca com bala de canhão :)

Comment: @Sergio Sim eu sei que usar o jQuery para este simples problema não é necessário,mas achei que é uma possível solução e que irá funcionar corretamente,mas sei que você está certo nisto,hahaha.

Answer (score 3):

Isto aqui não funciona e faz seu código falhar:

```
var obg = form[i].obrigatorio;
```

Como `obrigatorio` não é um atributo padrão do HTML, não existe uma propriedade automática de mesmo nome no objeto. Você precisa usar [`getAttribute`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/Element/getAttribute), e se quiser que seu HTML valide (como HTML5), precisa colocar o prefixo `data-` no nome do atributo, assim:

```
<input name="bla" data-obrigatorio="1">
```

E aí pode pegar o valor assim:

```
obg = form[i].getAttribute('data-obrigatorio');
```

A função completa ficaria:

```
function ValidaSemPreenchimento(form) {
    var i, obg, nome;
    for (i = 0; i < form.length; i++) {
        obg = form[i].getAttribute('data-obrigatorio'):
        if (obg == 1) {
            if (form[i].value == "") {
                nome = form[i].name;
                alert("O campo " + nome + " é obrigatório.")
                form[i].focus();
                return false;
            }
        }
    }
    return true;
}
```

Comment: Acho a tua resposta boa e válida, mas ainda estou na dúvida se esse `.obrigatorio` não será `name="obrigatorio"` do input... https://jsfiddle.net/uaht4r3L/

Comment: @Sergio O contexto me diz que é um atributo, mas posso estar errado.